# How to Share Wordpress site from vagrant environment?

Tags: wordpress, github, ssh, vagrant, share

Ok, so I developed a WordPress site using Vagrant on my desktop, but now I want to access and develop it on my laptop. I've run into the vagrant share command and am able to access it through ssh on my laptop. Is it as simple as using sftp over this connection, and if so, what files do I download? Will I need to make any other changes to my virtual box? I'm just not sure how to go about sharing this site. Do I need to use github?

Comment: You can use the https://bitbucket.org/ it free for private project. Github is free for open project but for private project you have to buy a membership.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need/want to share - If you only have a code base to share, as mentioned a cvs/svn/git system will work, you can use github or bitbucket; both have pro and cons.

If you need to share more about your site, including a database, if you made a lot of hack to make it work (on the system of your vagrant box or the site itself) you can repackage the VM box and use that as a new box when creating the new vagrantfile on your laptop.

From your desktop:

```
vagrant box repackage <boxname> virtualbox <version>
```

If you're not sure about the name, provider (here virtual box) and version arguments just run `vagrant box list` to see them listed

Then transfer the new box to your laptop and install as a new box

```
vagrant box add <boxname> <path_to_box_file>
vagrant init <boxname>
vagrant up
```

edit your Vagrantfile as needed after you generated with `vagrant init` and your website will be fully running as it is from your desktop

Comment: I think I will try the second method, with vagrant box repackaging. However, I already have a virtualbox installed on my laptop. I would like this packaged box to replace the one on my laptop. Will it automatically do that, or do I have to manually delete some folders?

Comment: Also, which directory should I do the vagrant box repackage and vagrant box add comands in...vagrant-local? (my main folder that contains everything aside from VirtualBox VMs, and some other folders like .VirtualBox and .vagrant.d

Comment: you need to run the `repackage` command from your current desktop project folder (where you have Vagrantfile) and you can add box from any folder - you dont need to change anything on your laptop, just you will add the new box generated from the desktop and vagrant will create a new VM that will be a brand copy of the one from your desktop, you dont need to change your other VMs

Comment: Tried $ vagrant box add package.box, but told me to add --name, so I did $ vagrant box add package.box --name and $ vagrant box add --name, but none worked.  Also, how do I go about deleting the old VM completely? I want this new one to completely replace it.

Comment: right you can run `vagrant box <boxname> package.box` to fully delete the old VM, run `vagrant destroy` from your old project, you can also run `vagrant global-status` and then `vagrant destroy <boxid>` from the id column of the VM you want to remove from your system

Comment: How do I find the box name? When I entered vagrant box list, it only says ubuntu/trusty64 (virtualbox, [LONG NUMBER]). I got rid of the actual number, because I'm not sure if that's a security risk to publish online.

Comment: you choose a box name so you set this up